# Android: Why values from BD are not being written in TextViews?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

This is may be a basic problem but I can't find the solution to it. I'm doing a query to my BD to get a value(DESPESA), and the value is correctly returned (I've proved it with Log.d) but it isn't, then, printed on the Activity and on the TextView.

Can you please help me?

My code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ver);

        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());

        Gasto gasto= new Gasto();
        gasto = databaseHelper.getGasto();

        int despesa = gasto.getDespesa_final();
        Log.d("LOG", "despesa->"+despesa);

        TextView despesa1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewDespesa2);
        despesa1.setText(String.valueOf(despesa));
```

XML file:

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.android.asminhasdespesas.VerActivity">

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
        android:paddingTop="100dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:text="Despesa:"
        android:id="@+id/TextViewDespesa1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="100dp"
        android:paddingLeft="500dp"
        android:id="@+id/TextViewDespesa2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextViewDespesa1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextViewPlafond2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextViewDespesa1" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Mr.Me thank you for your suggestion, it was the solution, please answer it for I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 500dp padding from left, unless you are running your code on a TV or something I doubt you can see it. Try and reduce that 500dp to 100 for example and see what happens.

```
....
<TextView
    android:paddingTop="100dp"
    android:paddingLeft="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/TextViewDespesa2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextViewDespesa1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextViewPlafond2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextViewDespesa1" />
....
```